# Disable the buttons on runtime

Tags: android

I want paste button only when I select copy option. When copy option is not selected the paste button should not come on the screen.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set an OnClickListener on your copy option and pass there a reference of your button. Then in `onClick(View v)` method:

```
button.setEnabled(true); // or false - depends on the state of your copy option
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setVisibility(View.GONE) method to hide the button when needed and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) to show it again.